# WP8 - Re-using a native DLL through Windows Runtime Component

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a native dll that I'd like to use in a WP8 project that I'm working on. I've done some research and have created a C++ Windows Runtime Component (WRC) to wrap the native DLL. The WRC project uses a .lib file, and my WP8 application calls the WRC project.

My solution compiles all fine, but when my application makes a call to a method in the native DLL, I get a `The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)` exception.

From reading around it seems like the dll is not being loaded. I've copied all relevant dlls to the output dir of where the .exe file is and also in various places but the error keeps showing up.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful. Also if more info is required I'll post that up also.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your issue yet? I have the same problem and I'm dying trying a way to load the library...

Answer (score 2):

The DLL must be included in your XAP package.  Something you can see being taken care of in the Output window when you build your app, it starts with the "Begin Xap packaging" messages and then lists all the files that get added.  The runtime error says it is not being included.

There is remarkably little guidance on how to ensure that a file gets included in a phone package when MSBuild cannot figure out the dependencies by itself.  It certainly won't for your DLL, no way the build system can tell if it isn't a project in your solution.  Seems you're operating a bit on the bleeding edge in this case :)

But this works well when I try it, going by the MSBuild output and not by actually testing it:  Project + Add Existing Item.  Navigate to your DLL and select it.  Select it in the Solution Explorer window and look in the Properties window.  Ensure that "Build Action" = Content, Copy to Output Directory = "Copy if newer".  Rebuild, you'll now see the file getting added to the XAP.  Which should solve this particular error.  There might be others :)

Comment: Thanks Hans but I'm still getting the same error. I'm using an express version of VS so my options are slightly different. For the dlls I've set the following values in the Properties pane: Content=True, File Type=Document, Included In Project = True. In the Properties Window (right click on dll then Properties) I have the following values "Excluded From Build=No, Content=Yes, Item Type=Managed resource compiler". Are these values correct?

P.S. I'm actually developing this for Windows 8, which I'm going to port to WP8 afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Desktop or Windows Store native DLLs are not binary compatible with Windows Phone, even if they are built for the same CPU architecture.

Therefore you will need to recompile your native DLL for the Windows Phone toolset.

**About Windows Runtime Components:**

On Windows Phone a Windows Runtime Component is itself a native DLL (.NET is not supported on the phone). The binaries of Windows Runtime Components cannot be shared between Windows Store apps and Windows Phone apps.

Comment: Hi Paul, Windows Runtime Component is the project type that allows you to wrap native DLL so it can be used by WP.

Comment: When I attempt to port the WRC from Windows 8 to WP8 maybe I will run into some issues; but right now I'm trying to figure my original issue out. At the bottom of this doc, there's a table that specifies creating and consuming WRC. It implies that WP8 can use a Windows 8 WRC. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714080(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CreatingandConsumingWindowsRuntimeComponents

Comment: That just says you can write separately write a WRC in Windows Phone and in Windows Store, not that you can share the binaries between the two. Of course you can share the vast majority of the source code.

Comment: It might not explicitly say you can share it, but Windows 8 is the only one where you can write a C# WRC but you can consume it in WP8. Anyway this isn't what I'm currently stuck on...

Comment: You can't consume a c# WRC on WP8.